# Changing radio button background image

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

How can I change the background image inside the active radio button
Instead of the default one (I am using redmond) I want to use aristo

```
.ui-radiobutton-icon {
 background-image:?????  /images/ui-icons_38667f_256x240.png.jsf)";
}
```

What is the syntax ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the radio button styling purely with CSS.

I would recommend a javascript library that allows you to do this, such as [UniformJS](http://uniformjs.com/) for jQuery.